# Phpmyadmin Not Working

Tags: server, phpmyadmin

I recently installed phpmyadmin onto ubuntu server 10.04 using

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

The installation went fine and everything was working including phpmyadmin. I then performed a restart of the server and now apache2 starts up but when I navigate to

```
http://192.168.1.72/phpmyadmin/
```

I am getting a 403 error. I have included /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf file in /etc/apahe2/apache2.conf file

```
/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

# phpMyAdmin default Apache configuration
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

            php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
            php_flag track_vars On
            php_flag register_globals Off
            php_value include_path .
    </IfModule>

</Directory>
# Authorize for setup
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup>
 <IfModule mod_authn_file.c>
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "phpMyAdmin Setup"
 AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup
 </IfModule>
 Require valid-user
</Directory>
#Disallow web access to directories that don't need it
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
   Order Deny,Allow
   Deny from All
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from All
</Directory>
```

The only change that was made since phpmyadmin was installed was that timetrex was installed. Is there anyway to manually start phpmyadmin or should it already be working once apache started?

Comment: Does it help to `chmod 755` to phpmyadmin folder?

Comment: it is currently set to 755. I don't see how adding a group write will allow it to run, seeing as it was running perfectly before I restarted apache

Comment: sorry, I meant 755... editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to solve my issue. I had left out

```
order deny,allow
#deny from all
allow from all
```

from `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`.

I found the solution to this problem from one of the Super User questions:

- [How can I start phpMyAdmin?](https://superuser.com/a/114258)